# ReactJS: Maintain data state between parent and child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There's a parent, `<MessageBox />` element, which contains a list of `messages` stored in its **state**. For each `message` in `messages`, a `<Message />` element is created inside `<MessageBox />` which has fields for `message.subject` and `message.body`. A user can edit the `message.subject` and `message.body` and once done, the `message` object is sent back to `<MessageBox />` through a `props.updateHandler()` to maintain the message state in the parent.

In my current approach, I'm storing the message data in `MessageBox`'s state and in the `render()` function, I'm creating the `<Message />` elements and passing a callback to each of them to send back data changes. In the callback, the updated data from each of the `<Message />` elements is updated back into `MessageBox`'s state. The reason for this is to keep all the recent updated data in one place only. The above approach creates havoc if `shouldComponentUpdate()` method in `<Message />` is not overloaded (infinite recursion).

Is there a better approach for this? I've to write a lot of code just to override the builtin methods to keep the entire thing stable. As I'm not planning to go for Flux/Redux, is there a React-only approach for this?

**EDIT: Since there's a lot of confusion, I'm adding minimal code.**

```js
class Message extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        this.state = {
            subject: this.props.subject,
            body: this.props.body,
            type: this.props.type,
            messageIndex: this.props.messageIndex
        };
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.props.updateHandler(messageIndex, {
            subject: this.state.subject,
            body: this.state.body,
            type: this.state.type
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    defaultValue={this.state.subject}
                    onBlur={e => this.setState({subject: e.target.value})} />

                <input
                    type="text"
                    defaultValue={this.state.subject}
                    onBlur={e => this.setState({body: e.target.value})} />

                <select
                    type="text"
                    value={this.state.subject}
                    onChange={e => this.setState({type: e.target.value})}>
                    <option>Type 1</option>
                    <option>Type 2</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class MessageBox extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        this.state = {
            messages: aListOfMessageObjects
        }
    }

    updateHandler(message) {
        // Message update happens here and returns a list updatedMessages
        this.setState({
            messages: updatedMessages
        });
    }

    render() {
        let _this = this;

        var messagesDOM = this.state.messages.map((m) => {
            return (
                <Message
                    message={m}
                    updateHandler={_this.updateHandler.bind(_this)} />
            );
        })

        return (
            <div>
                {messagesDOM}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't write why you need message.subject and message.body in the parent component. If you don't need it there, it's perfectly valid to pass them as props to a child component and make a state of a child out of them.

Comment: "In the callback, the updated data from each of the <Message /> elements is updated back into MessageBox's state." When this callback is triggered? This callback should be triggered only when user edits a message. I can't see any recursive loop this way. Could you provide some code implementation? I may misunderstood your implementation of MessageBox & Message.

Comment: @Maggie `message.body` and `message.subject` being a part of `message` will be sent back to the server via AJAX or bulk inserted or updated along with other `messages`. That's why I need all the `messages` data in one place.

Comment: @DamienLeroux In `<Message />`, I'm overriding the `componentDidUpdate()` method. Inside that, the current values from `Message`'s state are sent to the parent (`MessageBox`) by the callback (`props.updateHandler()`). When parent receives these updated values, it does a `setState()` again which causes all `<Messages />` to render and receive the new data. This again triggers `componentDidUpdate()` in each of `Message` and you have infinite recursion here.

Comment: I think it is a bad idea to have `componentDidUpdate()` updating it parent. Only `MessageBox` should have it `State` updated. Only `Message` should only render given props. All user interact with a message should trigger state mutation in `Message` only.

Comment: @DamienLeroux Agreed. But, what if I want the latest state of all messages in parent?

Comment: May be I not made myself clear enough :). There must be only one state. This state must be put into `MessageBox`. `Message` will receive only two props: `message` coming from parent state and `updateHandler` that is the parent callback that modify it state. Calling `updateHandler()` will modified the parent state and as a result will refresh `Message`. The key to your problem is to call `updateHandler()` at the right time. When do you want to call it?

Comment: @DamienLeroux I want to call it when any data inside `<Message />` has changed so that `<MessageBox />` also gets the updated data.

Comment: That's the problem: there should not be any data in `Message`. Only in `MessageBox `.  `Message` should be ony a displayer that track user interaction.

Comment: @DamienLeroux I've added minimal code in the question. Please have a look. Then, how to make `Message` only do user interaction? Using `props` instead of `state`?

Comment: You shouldn't be calling updateHandler from componentWillUpdate. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If that can help, read [thinking-in-react](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-2-build-a-static-version-in-react). It explains how data should go only one way to avoid be lost in UI updates.

[React ToDo MVC](http://todomvc.com/examples/react/#/) will provide you an example of React good practice on a real case

To know how to pass props from your parent to children read [controlled-components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components). you'll have to use `value` and `onBlur` on each input. Any `onBlur` event will call `this.props.updateHandler` with `e` as parameter instead of `e => this.setState({type: e.target.value})`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't do a callback to `MessageBox` from `componentDidUpdate()` of `Message`. Do a callback directly from an action in Message.
2. You don't need state in `Message` component at all. Props will keep the values you are interested if you update parent's state properly.

What you need is something like:

```
    <input type="text"
       defaultValue={this.props.subject}
       onBlur={e => this.updateSubject(e.target.value)} />

    updateSubject: function(newSubjectValue) {
         this.props.updateHandler(messageIndex, {
            subject: newSubjectValue,
            body: this.props.body,
            type: this.props.type
    });
    }
```

That way the component will get re-rendered, but won't do another call to the parent's setState.

Comment: I will give this a try.